# Conjectured analogue of Fermat's Little Theorem for Bernouli numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, bernoulli-numbers

Is the following analogue of Fermat's Little Theorem for Bernouli numbers true?

> Let $D_{2n}$ be the denominator of $\frac{B_{2n}}{4n}$ where $B_n$ is
> the $n$-th [Bernoulli number](http://oeis.org/A006863). If $\gcd(a, D_{2n}) = 1$ then
>
> $$ a^{2n} \equiv 1 \;(\bmod\; D_{2n}) $$

**Update** 18-Jan-2022: [Posted in MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414103/analogue-of-fermats-little-theorem-for-bernoulli-numbers?noredirect=1#comment1062090_414103)

Comment: What numerical evidence do you have?

Comment: @lhf Its true for all $a \le 10000, n \le 1000$

Comment: the tag "Bernoulli numbers" would be appropriate

Comment: To prove this it is sufficient to prove $$\lambda(D_{2n})\mid 2n$$ for every positive integer $n$ , where $\lambda(k)$ is the Carmichaelfunction. This gives a far more efficient search since we need not check any particular coprime number $a$. Upto $n=10^4$, this is true and therefore the conjecture. Range upto $n=10^5$ is still running.

Comment: Aborted at $n=2\cdot 10^4$ , no counterexample found.

Comment: A proof is essentially given in Section 5.1 of [Notes on primitive lambda-roots](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~pjc/csgnotes/lambda.pdf) by P. J. Cameron and D. A. Preece.

Answer (score 2):

If you work out the powers of a prime dividing $D_{2n}$ you get the following which is a well-known stronger version of the Clausen-von Staudt result.

If $p=2$, $\nu_2(D_{2n})=\nu_2(n)+3$.
If $p$ is odd and $(p-1)\mid 2n$ then $\nu_p(D_{2n})=\nu_p(n)+1$, otherwise $\nu_p(D_{2n})=0$.

Now for the congruence to hold you just need to check it modulo these powers of each prime and this is easy because of the structure of the group of units module a prime power.

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial proof that $a^{2n} - 1$ is divisible by the denominator of $D_{2n}$. Haven't been able to account for the additional factor $4n$.

The [Von Staudt–Clausen theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Staudt%E2%80%93Clausen_theorem) is that $D_{2n}$ is given by the product of all primes $p$ for which $p − 1|2n$. In particular, $D_{2n}$ is square free. Thus if $p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_k$ are the distinct prime factors of $D_{2n}$ then
$$p_1p_2 \ldots p_k = D_{2n}$$
$$(p_1-1)(p_2-1)\ldots (p_k-1) = 2n$$

If $\gcd(a,D_{2n}) = 1$ then by Fermat's Little theorem,

$$ a^{(p_1-1)(p_2-1)\ldots (p_k-1)} \equiv 1 \;(\bmod\; p_1) $$
$$ a^{(p_1-1)(p_2-1)\ldots (p_k-1)} \equiv 1 \;(\bmod\; p_2) $$
$$\cdots$$
$$ a^{(p_1-1)(p_2-1)\ldots (p_k-1)} \equiv 1 \;(\bmod\; p_k) $$

Since the moduli are all distinct primes, they have no common factor. Thus

$$ a^{(p_1-1)(p_2-1)\ldots (p_k-1)} \equiv 1 \;(\bmod\; p_1 p_2 \ldots p_k) $$

i.e. $a^{2n}-1$ is divisible by the denominator of $D_{2n}$.

Comment: What about the additional factor $4n$ in the denominator ? Do the primes not satisfying the condition cancel out with the numerator of the Bernoulli number ? This is what I wondered when trying a proof myself.

Comment: If this proof is correct, it is a great help to prove your other conjecture (and it can probably be even strengthened)

Comment: @Peter You are right, this is only a proof of the weaker claim that $a^{2n}-1$ is divisible by the denominator of $B_{2n}$. Haven't been able to account for the additional factor $4n$ so far.

Comment: I don't think we know that $(p_1 - 1) \cdots (p_k - 1) = 2n$, do we?  In any case this isn't necessary, since your proof only uses the fact that each $(p_i-1) | 2n$, which comes straight from the von Staudt-Clausen theorem.

Comment: I think you have confused $D_{2n}$ with the denominator of  $B_{2n}$.